# Footer floats to middle on the page

Tags: html, css, footer

Is there any way to set footer at the bottom of the page?
Footer should be 100% width and `.wrapper` 960px as well.

I already tried:

1. `position: relative;` - sticks between `.content` tags
2. `position: absolute;` - sticks to `.nav`
3. `position: fixed;` - could be a solution, but I don't need it all the time, just at bottom of the last page.
4. to move `.footer` outside `.wrapper` and set `.wrapper:not(footer);` - footer sticked to the bottom, but the width hasn't changed.

Any suggestion how is possible to set it up at the bottom?

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Nunito+Sans|Roboto&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

html,
body,
header,
main {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Roboto, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  background-image: url(../images/extra_clean_paper.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#hero-header {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#hero-btn {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4em;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.hero-btn a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s;
  -o-transition: opacity .3s;
  transition: opacity .3s;
}

.hero-btn a:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

header a {
  padding-top: 70px;
}

header a span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-left: -12px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-animation: sdb07 2s infinite;
  animation: sdb07 2s infinite;
  opacity: 0;
}

header a span:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

header a span:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: 16px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .15s;
  animation-delay: .15s;
}

header a span:nth-of-type(3) {
  top: 32px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .3s;
  animation-delay: .3s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sdb07 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes sdb07 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

#resp-nav {
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
  background-color: grey;
}

#resp-nav i {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
}

#nav {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: dimgray;
  z-index: 2;
}

main:not(#footer) {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 1em;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 3.125em 0.625em;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.aboutme img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.aboutme .col-40 {
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  width: 39%;
}

.aboutme .col-60 {
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  width: 59%;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.hobbies .table-row {
  display: table-row;
  border-bottom: 0.1em solid darkgrey;
}

.hobbies .table-row:last-child {
  border: 0;
}

.hobbies .table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
}

.portfolio .col-50 {
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  width: 49%;
}

.projects .flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.projects .col-33 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 33%;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 33%;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 33%;
  flex: 0 0 33%;
}

.projects .services-box {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px 5px 0 5px;
}

footer {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header id="link-hero-page">
  <div id="hero-header">
  </div>
</header>
<nav>
  <ul id="nav">
  </ul>
</nav>
<main>
  <section id="link-main" class="aboutme container">
    <div class="col-40 left">
    </div>
    <article class="col-60 right">
    </article>
  </section>
  <section id="link-hobbies" class="hobbies container">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-row">
        <article class="table-cell">
        </article>
      </div>
      <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell">
        </div>
        <article class="table-cell">
        </article>
      </div>
      <div class="table-row">
        <article class="table-cell">
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="link-portfolio" class="portfolio container">
    <article class="col-50 left">
    </article>
    <article class="col-50 right">
    </article>
  </section>
  <section id="link-projects" class="projects container">
    <div class="flex-row">
      <div class="col-33">
        <article class="services-box">
        </article>
      </div>
      <div class="col-33">
        <article class="services-box">
        </article>
      </div>
      <div class="col-33">
        <article class="services-box">
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="link-contacts" class="contacts container">

  </section>
</main>
<!--FOOTER-->
<footer>
  <address>
    <p style="text-align: center;">LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM</p>
   </address>
</footer>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1adkjLw0/

Comment: Transfer footer outside of wrapper

Comment: [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5q2asn0w/)

Comment: Kind a strange thing, it works here, but it doesn't work on my webpage. When I move it outside .wrapper it just jumps to the middle of page (between containers). [https://jsfiddle.net/1adkjLw0/](https://jsfiddle.net/1adkjLw0/)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to turn your container into a vertical flexbox and set `margin-top: auto` on the footer which will push it to the bottom of the flex container.  You also need to set `height: 100%` on the container so it fills the whole page

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
}

.nav {
  background: green;
  height: 50px;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  background: yellow;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 100px;
}

.footer {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="nav"></div>

<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>  
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>

  <div class="footer"></div>

</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move your footer outside of the wrapper.

```css
       * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
  }

  body {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .nav {
    background: green;
    height: 50px;
  }

  .wrapper {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .content {
    background: yellow;
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 100px;
  }

  .footer {
    background: red;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="nav"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>  
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Comment: Kind a strange thing, it works here, but it doesn't work on my webpage. When I move it outside .wrapper it just jumps to the middle of page (between containers). [https://jsfiddle.net/1adkjLw0/](https://jsfiddle.net/1adkjLw0/)